# kendo Sortable - Disable Ghost / Hint in Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-sortable

I am using kendo-sortable and need to disable this "ghost" box with the dragged item that kendo leaves in the place where the item was.

```
<kendo-sortable [kendoSortableBinding]="widgetsPosition.overviewTab.col1"...>
 </kendo-sortable>
```

I have not found anything in the documentation. it seems in previous versions worked:

```
 - (kendoSortableBeforeHint)="beforeHint($event)"
```

but it does not anymore.

Does anyone know how to disable that behaviour?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply some custom styling to hide and show the active item, e.g.:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jufe2d-zmegxn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts